# Is it possible to host a static html website in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, static

How do I set index.html for the default root web page?

```
application: dfischerdna version: 1
 runtime: python api_version: 1

 handlers:

 - url: /   
   static_dir: static_files
```

This works great when the visitor types 
http://dfischerdna.appspot.com/index.html

However I would like that when he types this, the index.html web page would be displayed.
http://dfischerdna.appspot.com/ -> goes to 404 page

Comment: Great idea. This is 5 times faster than building the response with a string from memcache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do the trick for you:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: path/to/index.html
  upload: local/path/to/index.html
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: path/to/\1
  upload: local/path/to/(.+)
```

The first url section will match the root URL and serve `path/to/index.html`. The second will match any path other than the root path, and will serve the file located under `path/to` that the request URI matches. For the URL `http://yourapp.appspot.com/index.html` it will serve `path/to/index.html`, and for a URL like `http://yourapp.appspot.com/foo/bar.html` it will serve `path/to/foo/bar.html`.

The upload directive tells GAE which local files to upload to serve as static files in your app instance.

Comment: With `static_files` directives, you also need to provide an `upload` directive to tell appcfg.py which files you want uploaded.

Comment: how do i write the upload directive?

Comment: @Wobble @unknown Right, I forgot. An example of the upload directive:

handlers:
- url: static_files: path/to/index.html
  static_files: path/to/index.html
  upload: local/path/to/index.html
- url: static_files: path/to/(.+)
  static_files: path/to/\1
  upload: local/path/to/(.+)

Comment: This works like charm in development mode on my local, but when I deploy it to the production I get "Static file referenced by handler not found:".. anythoughts what might be wrong here?